# Sending and receiving session state info (user data) while exchanging WhatsApp messages

Tags: node.js, express, twilio, whatsapp

I am new in Twilio and want to use it for connecting an existing chatbot to WhatsApp. Setting up a basic bi-directional message exchange (using the Twilio sandbox) turned out to be quite simple. I use `node.js` + `Express` in combination with the npm `twilio` package.

The chatbot is set up stateless. Therefore, what I need is a mechanism to keep track of the state the chatbot is in for a particular user.

*Question*: is it possible to send session state info (session data) back and forth with the WhatsApp message flow?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this behavior also applies to the WhatsApp message flow, otherwise the answer is no. Curious on your findings.

How do Twilio cookies work?
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136287-How-do-Twilio-cookies-work-

Answer (score 0):

I submitted my question to Twilio Support; below is (part of) the answer I got.

*Twilio Support*:

Unfortunately, our WhatsApp integration does not support cookies. Instead, I would strongly recommend our Conversations API:

- https://www.twilio.com/conversations
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/quickstart

This would allow you to create meaningful connections with customers across channels.  You could integrate Twilio autopilot to build an intelligent chatbot.

- https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012060714-Getting-Started-with-Twilio-Autopilot
- https://www.twilio.com/autopilot
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot